# Why does py2app create a folder path outside the app?

Tags: python, numpy, py2app

I've used py2app with code that imports numpy. py2app creates the app, which runs properly, but only if the app resides in the same directory as a folder whose directory structure is opt/openblas/lib/libopenblas.0.dylib.

Is there a way to instruct py2app to bundle libopenblas.0.dylib with the app?

py2app for Mac on m1.